# ActiveRecord raw sql slower than MySql

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, performance, activerecord

I would like that someone help me to understand why executing a raw sql query from ActiveRecord(33.6 s) is less performant that Mysql(14.0 s).

The query is the following:

```
SELECT 
      CASE 
        WHEN
        WeekDay(c.collect_date) >=0 AND WeekDay(c.collect_date) <5 THEN 1
      ELSE 0 
      END AS is_business_day, 
      HOUR(c.collect_date) consumption_hour, 
        SUM(c.energy), 
        AVG(c.power) 
    FROM consumptions c
    INNER JOIN devices d ON c.device_id=d.device_id AND d.ftp_id=1    
    GROUP BY CASE WHEN
        WeekDay(c.collect_date) >=0 AND WeekDay(c.collect_date) <5 THEN 1
      ELSE 0 
      END, HOUR(c.collect_date)
```

And below are the screenshot with the times.

[image: Active Record time]

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: because you are going thru extra layers of tomfoolery. I am surprise it doesn't take longer

Comment: What does  `consumption_tiers` do? Typical Rails queries take a lot longer than plain SQL because they instantiate many objects.

Comment: @ahmacleod that scope just execute the query, so it doesn't justify to waste too much time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering the times taken from profiling([see Rails Github issue](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/21590)), the conclusion is:

> > The wasted time by ActiveRecord is similar to Mysql, but slower than *Mysql WorkBench**